# Mapbox GL JS Controls Go Off the Map when Resizing a styled-components Container in React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, mapbox-gl-js

I have a basic Mapbox GL Map component in React, whose container is styled using styled-components. There is an action in the application which causes the map container to resize based on a user input.

However, when the map resizes, both the scale control and the navigation controls are no longer within the map container. I am able to resolve this by fixing the position of the nav controls in the css, but it doesn't help me for the scale bar.

Is there a reason why these elements fly off the map container? Here is a snippet of the code, and a styled component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { MapContainer } from './styled'

const MapContainer = styled('section')`
  width: 100vw;
  height: ${props => props.height};
`

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { lat, lng, zoom } = this.props

    this.state = {
      lng,
      lat,
      zoom
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { accessToken } = this.props
    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state

    mapboxgl.accessToken = accessToken
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapContainer,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom
    })

    const scale = new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({
      maxWidth: 80,
      unit: 'metric'
    })

    this.map.addControl(scale)

    this.map.addControl(
      new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({ showCompass: false }),
      'top-left',
    )

    this.map.once('load', () => {
      this.map.resize()
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { height } = this.props

    if (prevProps.height !== height) {
      this.map.resize()
    }
  }


  render() {
    const { height } = this.props

    return (
        <MapContainer
          height={height}
          ref={el => {
            (this.mapContainer = el)
          }}
        />
    )
  }
}


export default Map
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because styled-components generates new class names when the map container resizes. The new class names will no longer include the `mapboxgl-map` class which was originally added when `new mapboxgl.Map()` was called.

Try adding `mapboxgl-map` as a `className` property to the `<MapContainer>` component to ensure the class name is maintained:

```
<MapContainer
      className='mapboxgl-map'
      height={height}
      ref={el => {
        (this.mapContainer = el)
      }}
    />
```

Credit to Brendan McGill for pinning this issue down and providing more detail here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6946